# Negative Look-back in preg_replace() with numbered Backreferences, has no effect

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, regex-lookarounds

I have a regex function that will take my input $text and return the same text, but with anything that looks remotely like a web address formatted as an embedded `<a href></a>`.

```
preg_replace('@(http)?(s)?(://)?(([-\w]+\.)+([^\s]+)+[^,.\s])@', '<a href="http$2://$4">$1$2$3$4</a>', $text)
```

Example outputs:
`http://www.example.com` => `<a href="http://www.example.com">http://www.example.com</a>`
 `https://www.example.com` => `<a href="https://www.example.com">https://www.example.com</a>`
 `www.example.com` => `<a href="http://www.example.com">www.example.com</a>`

Now, I would like to extend it so that it does **not** do this when it comes across a web address that has a " right in front of it -- I'm trying to prevent it from re-embedding addresses that are already inside href="" properties.  So, I tried adding a negative look-back, like so:

```
preg_replace('@(?<!")(http)?(s)?(://)?(([-\w]+\.)+([^\s]+)+[^,.\s])@', '<a href="http$2://$4">$1$2$3$4</a>', $text)
```

It *was* my understanding that a negative lookback would not capture anything.  Unfortunately, adding the lookback not only doesn't stop the engine from replacing the pattern on addresses prepended by a double quote, it also ends up totally mangling the output.  I can't figure out if it is the ? operators messing up the lookback, or if the parentheses around the lookback are actually throwing off my backreferences in the replacement rule.  Again -- I *thought* they did not contribute any captured patterns.

Comment: post the input string first and then then the pattern you tried.

Comment: It's because of `(http)?(s)?`. Both parts are optional but they shouldn't be.

Comment: Here's two input strings I've tried, $text=""www.example.com" and $text="www.example.com".  Further, how can those parts not be optional?  `http://www.example.com`, `https://www.example.com`, and `www.example.com` should all be caught by the pattern.

Comment: I would use a dom parser and process text sections only..

Comment: Avinash, I cannot.  That is the purpose of the pattern!

Comment: Should it match things starting with `www` or any dot separated string?

Comment: @user57092 post the expected output for the inputs `http://www.example.com, https://www.example.com, and www.example.com`

Comment: @user57092 did you mean this http://regex101.com/r/aW0sT4/1 ?

Comment: Wow!  Nice regex environment!  And an even better solution!  Yes, this is the behaviour I desire.  Put it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest this regex that doesn't require any anchoring (thus can be used on a page containing links and text):

```
<a href\s?=\s?"http(s)?://([^"]+)">([^<]+)</a>|(http)?(s)?(://)?((?:[-\w]+\.)+\S+[^,.\s])
```

Usage:

```
$result = preg_replace('~<a href\s?=\s?"http(s)?://([^"]+)">([^<]+)</a>|(http)?(s)?(://)?((?:[-\w]+\.)+\S+[^,.\s])~', '<a href="http$1$5://$2$7">$3$4$5$6$7</a>', $text);
```

The regex matches both the 'normal' urls and the ones that are already wrapped between anchor tags, but treats them differently in the replace.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below regex to embed a site address inside `<a>` tag and don't do the embeding on already embeded site adresses.

**Regular expression:**

```
^(?!<a href.*$)(http)?(s)?(:\/\/)?(([-\w]+\.)+([^\s]+)+[^,.\s])
```

**Substitution:**

```
<a href="http$2://$4">$1$2$3$4</a>
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/aW0sT4/2)

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
$mystring = <<<EOT
http://www.example.com
https://www.example.com
www.example.com
<a href="http://www.example.com">http://www.example.com</a>
EOT;
$pattern = "~^(?!<a href.*$)(http)?(s)?(:\/\/)?(([-\w]+\.)+([^\s]+)+[^,.\s])~m";
$replacement = '<a href="http$2://$4">$1$2$3$4</a>';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $mystring);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">http://www.example.com</a>
<a href="https://www.example.com">https://www.example.com</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com">www.example.com</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com">http://www.example.com</a>
```

Comment: Your pattern is false and works only on the test example, because you use the start of line anchor `^` with the m modifier. I assume that in real life URLs are not always at the begining of the line.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Then how it would be written without anchor and $ .op didn't mention about the url's in a page.

Comment: Don't be naive, urls are probably in a page! A way is to use `(<a\s.*?</a>)|urlpattern` with `preg_replace_callback`. When the group1 is defined you return it, when it is not defined you return the whole match embedded between "a" tags.

Comment: Note too that in `(?!<a href.*$)(http)?(s)?(:\/\/)?(([-\w]...` the lookahead is always true since the next character can't be an angle bracket.

Comment: Casimir's words are true.  I have learned a lot about regex today :)

Answer (score 0):

Both Avinash Raj and Jerry have provided solutions that match the parameters and requirements as stated in my question, and have expanded my knowledge of regex considerably.  Unfortunately, I found that both solutions started substituting strings with period-delimited addresses inside `iframe src` properties, `mailto:` addresses (after the @ sign), et cetera.

After quite a few attempts to get the regex to compensate for all these possibilities, as the first alternative in Jerry's solution compensates for addresses inside `<a>` tags, I have concluded that Jack, who posted the very first solution here (and which is no longer extant) was correct; I simply cannot provide the protocol guesswork for my users.  So I have changed the requirements:  the protocol is necessary, and the user must specify http(s) or ftp(s).  This is not what was requested of me, but I cannot think of a better solution.  To this end, [I devised this (considerably simpler) regex and substitution](http://regex101.com/r/oJ5hO1/2) rule as follows:

**Regex:**

```
~(?<!["'>])(http|ftp)(s)?://((?:[-\w]+\.)+\S+[^,.\s])~g
```

**Substitution:**

```
<a href="$1$2://$3">$3</a>
```

I am posting this as a separate answer because it is technically not beholden to the parameters that both Avinash and Jerry were maintaining, and which constitute my question as written.  The simple fact of the matter is, I can't have a solution that is mangling iframes and other such elements which I have no control over.  But I can't think of a better way than to require the users to include the protocol for their links.  I think it is the most logical compromise, but if someone has a better solution, I'd love to hear about it.

Thank you all for your insight into the nature of regex and special thanks to Avinash again for showing me regex101.